# Disable playback looping in timeline

Tags: timeline, loop

I'm attempting to do a walk animation with Auto keying. But when I reach the end of the timeline, it loops back to the beginning and overwrites my previously animated camera...

Is there a way to disable the timeline's loop function so it doesn't replay after hitting the end?

(Yes I saw this question has been asked before but the answer involved scripting... Which by Blender 3.5, I would assume there's a real function I can tick just to simply disable it)

Comment: From what I know you can't